# problems in \cite{} with IEEEtran

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran

`\cite{1,2}` is expected to give

> [1,2]

however, when I use the `IEEEtran.cls`, the output is

> [1],[2]

I have tried this using the `article` class and it was OK.

Comment: The IEEE style _is_ '[1],[2]': this is quite deliberate with this class. Are you using it for some purpose other than submitting to the IEEE?

Comment: @JosephWright how can I close this question?

Comment: @zsf222 If it's just a misunderstanding about `IEEEtran` then yes, probably 'off-topic' (not actually a TeX problem).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about TeX - LaTeX.